# Insert into table from another with different columns count (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Question, why this dose not work?

```
create table one (a int(1) default 1, b int(2));

create table two (b int(1));

insert into one select * from two;
```

error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

a know it, a can count, but why, **philosophically**?
database knows, what the name of inserting column from table `two` is `b`, knows that the column `a` in table `one` has a default value equal `1`..
so, what problem of executing this query?

And general - How can i do this differently, not manual, without information of a columns and their count, if this way is impossible?

I know this:
**table `two` always have all the same columns, that the table `one` have. But table `one` have another columns too, that have a some default values.**

Is there some way to do that? insert all data from `two` in `one`, and fill the remaining columns by some default or other values!

Need help!
Thank you very match!

Comment: insert into one(b) select b from two;

Answer (score 4):

When you run:

```
insert into one
    select * from two;
```

The SQL engine automatically puts in the columns that are implied.

- For the `insert`, this is the list of columns in declaration order.
- For the `*`, this is the list of columns in declaration order.

There is no "matching" of columns by names, only lists of columns in each table.

So, the query is really:

```
insert into one(a, b)
    select b from two;
```

That looks like an error to me.

Moral of the story?  Write that code that you intend.  Always include columns lists, particularly for `insert` statements.  So write:

```
insert into one(b)
    select b from two;
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that.

But this means, that i must always know the name of the **same** columns, that must be inserting **automaticly** in my opinion, because both tables have them. Why i must have set this names manualy? 
ok...
it is very strange for relational theory of database..

and eventually - so, this task **can not** be solved in SQL?
Maybe some easy way with minimal programming is and maximum SQL? Because name of columns - i did't know them. I know that the table `one` have all the same columns that table `two`, and some more columns with default values.

Thank you!

Comment: PS. I have done this task with some additional programming, thanx for answer `insert into one(b) select b from two;`!