# Postgres insert data from one table to another where column names match

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert

*Abstract*

I have one main table with columns named A through Z. I have a dozen other tables that also have strictly letter-named columns (same data types too), just not all columns from A to Z. (e.g. one tables may contain columns A,C,H while another contains columns A,B,C,X,Y,Z etc)

Assuming main table has defaults for all columns A through Z, is there a way to select every other tables' records into it without specifying each column name?

I know it is best to be explicit, but in reality I'm dealing with hundreds of fields, not 26, so I'm hoping there's a better way that's eluded me.

*Concrete*

I am trying to store annual data in one table (has additional year column). Each year, all existing fields remain from the previous year, but new fields may be added. I have imported each year's data into its own table (25 of them) and would like to consolidate. Most recent year/main table contains hundreds of columns.

I found a similar question here [Insert into table from another with different columns count (MySql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647999/insert-into-table-from-another-with-different-columns-count-mysql) but answer lists all columns explicitly in insert.

Comment: sounds like a hugely messed up database design to me.

Comment: You should be inserting a new *row* for each year rather than new *columns*.

Comment: @e4c5 not helpful as I don't have control over the data collection or structure. Before I normalize, I'd like to consolidate, and I'm hoping to keep the solution in postgres.

Comment: @gordon perhaps you misunderstand. For each year, there is a table filled with data for that year. I plan to have one table contain all data for all years, so naturally it needs a "year" column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - meant appending rows (i.e., stacking annual datasets). To add columns is restructuring a table which is not advised if in production requiring offline time. You want to stack your data in long format not wide, so add rows. Keep only one *year* column. Queries are easier to write, tables easier to maintain, storage more efficient.

Comment: @MarcDePoe . . . I think you're going to have to go through the effort of combining all the columns needed from each table.  There isn't a simple short-cut, although you could have fun playing with the `information_schema` views.

Comment: @Parfait - yes I have every intention of stacking rows, essentially a union (with a single year column added). As is, the redundancy is the width measured in tables.

Comment: @gordon - I'll likely end up scripting something outside of postgres, it's just frustrating that it's seemingly either name all explicitly or rely on strict column order with no native matching mechanism in between.. outside of information_schema gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that there could be various reasons to do this, I think you would better off be looking at something like table inheritance to provide a unified query interface for previous tables.  There are of course difficulties here.  But that is probably a better solution if you can.  Note the adding new fields would be very different if you go with inheritance.

The next option you would have would be to create an SQL mapping for each table to the archive table.  So if you have an additional year int field, you need to fill you could:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mytable_to_archive(mytable) returns archive language sql as
$$
select $1.*, null::int as year;
$$ IMMUTABLE;
```

Note for performance reasons, this just takes in a tuple, and returns a tuple.  No db lookups.  Then you could:

```
INSERT INTO archive
SELECT (mytable_to_archive(mytable)).* from mytable;
```